# Adjust the vertical distance between \sectionrule (package sectsty) and the following text

Tags: rules, sectsty

Given the package `sectsty` and the following code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.2pt}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Life}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the vertical distance between the horizonatal line (underneath the word "Life") and the lipsum text, just by acting on the command `\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.2pt}}`?

Comment: What do you mean with “adjust“?  Increase or decrease?

Comment: I mean both of them... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can define another command, that uses `\sectionrule`, for example:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\adaptedsectionrule}[6]{%
  \sectionrule{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#6\rule[-#5]{0pt}{#5}}% invisible rule used to increase the distance below

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\adaptedsectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.2pt}{1em}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Life}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

But IMHO a better solution would be to change the distance after `\section`:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {4.5ex \@plus.2ex}% original 2.3ex \@plus .2ex
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\SS@sectfont}}
\makeatother

\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.2pt}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Life}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

BTW: Current version of `sectsty` is not fully compatible with current LaTeX, because the definition of `\underbar` has changed. LaTeX defines it protected now, but the redefinition of `sectsty` is still not robust.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! If ```sectsty``` is not robust, what would you suggest as an alternative package/tool?
P.S.; Your first solution (i.e. before "But IMHO a better solution...") works, but I do not see any difference between your second solution (i.e. after "But IMHO a better solution...") and ```\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{0.2pt}}```.....

Comment: The first solution is only a hack with an invisible line of large depth. It cannot be used to decrease the distance.

Comment: If you don't have a problem with the incompatibility (or the warning message) of `sectsty`, use it. You just should know, that sometimes you may need to use `\protect\underbar` instead of `\underbar` (e.g. inside the argument of `\section` or `\caption`). But if you think, this is a problem: There are a lot of alternatives. For example classes `scrartcl` or `memoir` or package `titlesec` provide features to change the formatting of sectioning commands.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot !! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `titlesec` instead of `sectsty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
  [{\titlerule[0.2pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {3.5ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}
  {4ex plus 0.2ex}% <-- standard is 2.3ex plus 0.2ex

\begin{document}

\section*{Life}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I marked the argument where the spacing after the section title is defined. Look in the documentation of `titlesec` for the standard values (section 8.2).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg! I switched from  `sectsty` to `titlesec` since, the latter looks easier to use to me.... :-) Should I then change the accepted answer? Btw, I upvoted your answer..